# Column Adding and Filling it with Workbook Name for all workbooks in a folder

Tags: batch-file, excel, vba

What I'm in need of is somewhat complicated and challenging, an I don't know anywhere else to ask for help. I have several excel files, named like thb201301221.xls,thb20130201.xls , and the naming convention used in these files are like thb + date of the file created + (1 or 2). In each file, there are several sheets. I'm interested in certain sheets, named as N1-1, N1-2 AND N1-3. What I need to do is:

1. Combine these N1-1, N1-2 AND N1-3 sheets into one sheet for all
   workbooks
2. Add a column to beginning of each of these sheets and fill it with
   the date in the workbook name (in the file thb201301221.xls it's
   22.01.2013)
3. Create a workbook and a worksheet within it and fill it with these
   newly created worksheets, which are combination of N1-1, N1-2 AND
   N1-3 sheets in the workbooks.

Can someone help me in achieving this task. I can't possibly thinking of doing this manually and I'd really appreciate for your help.

Thanks already,
Korhan

Comment: Is there any code you have tried?  What was the result?

Answer (score 0):

You will not get a question like this answered here.  You have asked for too much in one go and you have not shown a minimal understanding of how to solve the problem.  We are here to help you improve your code not write it for you.

Break your total problem down into steps 1, 2, 3, ... N.  Write macros that perform step 1, step 1 and 2, step 1, 2 and 3 and so on.  If you have trouble with step X then ask about step X and show us the code that does not do what you expect.

**EDIT** IN my original answer I said I could go further than step 3 without knowing more. Do you want all the N1-1, N1-2 and N1-3 worksheets combined into a single worksheet or will you have three separate worksheets?  I later realised that I could go further if I was vague about worksheet names.

My steps for your problem :

1. Create a list of the workbooks of interest.
2. If sequence is important, is that list in the correct sequence? If Yes and No, sort the list.
3. Add an empty workbook to the Workbooks collection ready to receive the combined data.
4. Rename worksheeet "Sheet1" and other worksheets as necessary.
5. Loop through the [sorted] list of workbooks, opening each workbook, copying the required information from the source to destination worksheets and closing the workbook

For step 1, you will need either the Dir$ function or the Files property of the Folders Object.  You should be able to find either using the Visual Basic Help.  Dir$ is the older function and is probably easier to understand.  Folder Objects and their properties (for example Files) are more flexible and complete but may be harder to understand.  Note: Dir and Dir$ look the same but Dir$ is marginally more efficient.

Get each workbook name and use `Debug.Print FileName` to prove you have got the workbooks you want.  If your code for step 1 does not work, ask a question about it.

If you need to sort the list, search for "excel vba sort an array".

Next search for "excel vba add an empty workbook to the Workbooks collection".

For step 5 you will need to use the `Copy statement` which looks like: `RngSource.Copy Destination := RngDestination`.  You will need to identify the size of the source range and specify RngSource.  The Destination range will be the same size but the first row will be one more than the last row used and the first column will be 2 not 1 so you can fill in column 1 with the date from the filename.

I hope you get the idea.  If your steps are small enough and well defined enough, you should have no difficulty in finding some suitable code to add to your growing macro.  If you run into difficulties, a **small** question here will usually yield something helpful.